Every time I try to install apps on Ubuntu 22, I get certificate/ssl/update errors. Anyone know why?
I'm on a corporate laptop dual booted with Ubuntu and Windows. Whenever I try to install things like Caddy, Docker Desktop, or really any application it turns into a whole thing and I can't install them. I'm also new to Linux so I don't understand the seemingly arbitrary strings of numbers and letters that represent files(?) in Ubuntu.
I've attempted to clear my caches, re-install certificates, use gpt instead of apt-key (apparently it's deprecated but still defaults to it?), etc. When I try to run 'apt update', any non-standard applications are ignored and I get errors back.
Edit: Here's the error I get for step one, doing an apt-get update
Ign:2 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Err:2 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 146.112.250.208 443]
Fetched 2,054 kB in 8s (267 kB/s)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 146.112.250.208 443]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

openssl s_client -connect download.docker.com:443 response:
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, ST = California, L = San Francisco, O = Cisco, CN = Cisco Umbrella Primary SubCA
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=1 O = Cisco, CN = Cisco Umbrella Secondary SubCA nyc-SG
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = California, L = San Francisco, O = "Cisco Systems, Inc.", CN = download.docker.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:C = US, ST = California, L = San Francisco, O = "Cisco Systems, Inc.", CN = download.docker.com
   i:O = Cisco, CN = Cisco Umbrella Secondary SubCA nyc-SG
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 2048 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: Jun 16 11:33:13 2024 GMT; NotAfter: Jun 21 11:33:13 2024 GMT
 1 s:O = Cisco, CN = Cisco Umbrella Secondary SubCA nyc-SG
   i:C = US, ST = California, L = San Francisco, O = Cisco, CN = Cisco Umbrella Primary SubCA
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 2048 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: Jun 16 19:01:12 2024 GMT; NotAfter: Jun 27 19:01:12 2024 GMT
 2 s:C = US, ST = California, L = San Francisco, O = Cisco, CN = Cisco Umbrella Primary SubCA
   i:O = Cisco, CN = Cisco Umbrella Root CA
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 2048 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: May 14 18:21:48 2024 GMT; NotAfter: May 14 18:21:48 2029 GMT
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[SERVER CERTIFICATE REMOVED]
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=C = US, ST = California, L = San Francisco, O = "Cisco Systems, Inc.", CN = download.docker.com
issuer=O = Cisco, CN = Cisco Umbrella Secondary SubCA nyc-SG
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA-PSS
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3724 bytes and written 401 bytes
Verification error: unable to get local issuer certificate
---
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
---
---
Post-Handshake New Session Ticket arrived:
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.3
    Cipher    : TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Session-ID: [SESSION-ID-REMOVED]
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Resumption PSK: [PSK-REMOVED]
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 7200 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    [TLS-SESSION-TICKET-REMOVED]
    Start Time: 1718807630
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
    Extended master secret: no
    Max Early Data: 0
---
read R BLOCK
---
Post-Handshake New Session Ticket arrived:
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.3
    Cipher    : TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Session-ID: [SESSION-ID-REMOVED]
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Resumption PSK: [PSK-REMOVED]
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 7200 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    [TLS-SESSION-TICKET-REMOVED]
    Start Time: 1718807630
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
    Extended master secret: no
    Max Early Data: 0
---
read R BLOCK


Instead of describing them in vague terms, why not include the exact error messages in your question?

Please update the question with the exact commands and the messages / errors they  return.

Done, thanks you two! I updated with the first error I usually run into, will add more if I can't easily fix it from here.

Usually this means you have something going on with the certificate and potential interception at play.  This is an HTTPS certificate validation failure, and is not Uncommon to see with any kind of corporate network or a network where you have HTTPS interception at play.  Include the output of openssl s_client -connect download.docker.com:443 in your question as an edit please.

I don't see the output from the command requested - unless you haven't edited it in fully yet.

The lack of Ubuntu repositories in the output is suspicious. If accurate, it means no security updates, no bugfixes. Most unwise.

The other repos in the list there were accepted, I only included the ones that got ignored plus the error in the post.
